# How can I count the occurrences of a word in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a python script that looks through a log file and tells us how many times the user bin appears so have I have this:

```
#open the auth.log for reading
myAuthlog=open('auth.log', 'r')
for line in myAuthlog:
    if re.match("(.*)(B|b)in(.*)", line):
        print line
```

this prints out the full lines e.g.

```
>>> Feb  4 10:43:14 j4-be02 sshd[1212]: Failed password for bin from 83.212.110.234 port 42670 ssh2
```

But I only want to produce the number of times e.g. the user attempted to log in 26 times

Comment: You don't need the surrounding `.*` unless you explicitly are trying to extract the surrounding text

Comment: `count = sum(1 for line in myAuthlog if re.match("(.*)(B|b)in(.*)", line))`

Comment: So increment a counter instead of printing.

Comment: `print len(re.findall("(.*)(B|b)in(.*)", myAuthlog))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count = 0
myAuthlog=open('auth.log', 'r')
for line in myAuthlog:
    if re.match("(.*)(B|b)in(.*)", line):
        count+=1
print count
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

If your file is not gigantic, you can use `re.findall` and get the length of the resulting list:

```
count = len(re.findall(your_regex, myAuthlog.read()))
```

Option 2:

If your file is very large, iterate over the lines in a generator expression and sum up the matches:

```
count = sum(1 for line in myAuthlog if re.search(your_regex, line))
```

Both options assume that you want to count the number of lines for which you get a match, as your sample code indicates. Option 1 also assumes that the username can appear once per line.

A note about your regex:

`(.*)(B|b)in(.*)` will also match strings like `'Carabinero'`, consider using word boundaries, i.e.  `\b(B|b)in\b`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@cricket_007's comment (no need for `.*`, as long as you switch to `re.search` which doesn't implicitly insert a start of line anchor at the front)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490325/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-word-in-python#comment58673560_35490325), searching for bin with no other qualifiers is likely to get a lot of false positives. And using grouping parens makes the check more expensive (it has to store capture groups). Lastly, you should *always* use raw strings for regexes, or it will eventually bite you. Put together, you could use the regex with `if re.search(r'\b[Bb]in\b', line):` to enforce word boundaries, avoid unnecessary capture, and still do what you intend.

You could even optimize it a bit by pre-compiling the regex (Python caches compiled regular expressions, but it still involves executing Python level code to check the cache every time; a compiled object goes straight to C with no delays).

This lets you simplify to:

```
import re

# Compile and store bound method with useful name; use character classes
# to avoid capture of B/b, and word boundary assertions to avoid capturing
# longer words containing name, e.g "binary" when you want bin
hasuser = re.compile(r'\b[Bb]in\b').search

#open the auth.log for reading using with statement to close file deterministically
with open('auth.log') as myAuthlog:
    # Filter for lines with the specified user (in Py3, would need to wrap
    # filter in list or use sum(1 for _ in filter(hasuser, myAuthlog)) idiom
    loginattempts = len(filter(hasuser, myAuthlog))
print "User attempted to log in", loginattempts, "times"
```